# Find ID from data with API in Codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

In this code, I make a connection with the API to another company to get my information and to display it in my view :
[image]

This is my view where I display the data from API.
[image]
My question is how can I get the data if I click on the row to display me just the data of that row.

So let me say I take BedrijfsID 1 from EMCO BELGIUM NV: if I click on that I want a new view with only the details of that company.

function klant(){

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.onlinefact.be/customers.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"demo:demo");
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$this->view_data['klant'] = array($result);
$this->content_view = 'clients/klant';
}
```

Comment: If there is an api available which can give you data by company id ( data of that particular company ), call that api. Else you can store api response in an array and show in view accordingly.

Comment: You'd make it easier for people to help you if you'd actually put the code in your question, and not just take a picture of it.

Comment: I hope the data is not real

Comment: Nope its an demo kind of dummy tekst